# Using 'Date Deceased' in CiviReport

Tags: civireport

I'm attempting to create a basic Contact Summary CiviReport:  A list of deceased contacts sorted by Date Deceased. The field 'Date Deceased' from the Contact Summary doesn't appear to be an available column in CiviReport nor is it sortable.

Am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use [Data processor](https://civicrm.org/extensions/data-processor) extension, you can output the result as search or report or dashlet.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, however you can do this with the new Search Kit. It's currently an optional extension under Admin - System Settings - Extensions. After enabling there's a new option under the Search menu.